# Nginx запуск python приложений

Tags: python, nginx

Добрый день, подскажите, пожалуйста. Мне нужно запускать различные python-программы, которые пишу, посредством nginx. Для этого воспользовался  [вот этим](http://www.py-my.ru/post/4d34926d1d41c819a7000010)

Для запуска просто одной программы это работает, но если мне нужно перейти, например по такому адресу http://localhost/server.html то перехода не происходит, вообще работает только как-бы начальная страница и одна программа.

Как сделать чтобы можно было переходить по разным адресам? Т.е. http://localhost/server.html; http://localhost/1.py, http://localhost/2.py и т.д.

Я как понимаю нужно с какими-то другими параметрами запускать uwsgi, но мне не понятно как.

Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: работают url с .py в конце, но не работают с .html? что пишет error.log nginx?

Comment: Всё я разобрался, вопрос можно считать закрытым. Дело не в адресах, дело в моём недостаточном понимании настройки данной связки. Нужно или настраивать вебсервер или же на уровне приложения делать урлы.

Comment: я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что автор нашёл свою ошибку, но вряд ли уже когда-нибудь расскажет подробности.